# Aplicar una sentencia update, al subir fichero a tabla mysql

Tags: mysql

El seguiente script toma un fichero y lo coloca en una tabla, lo que busco agregar es una sentencia update de uno de los campos agregados, donde si el importe que (campo mysql decimal(8,2)) es menor a 0, coloque en campo num_boletos de esa fila insertada, un -1.
Caso contrario coloque un 1.

Pero no estoy seguro donde colocar dicha sentencia, o si es mejor manejarla con un if(sentencia,verdadero,falso).

La idea es que al momento de hacer la inserción del fichero, evalue actualize el campo num_boletos: poner -1 si el campo importe es menor que 0. Caso contrario colocar 1.

```html
load data local infile 'c:\\ventas\\vtascopia.txt' 
into table ventas306 
fields terminated by '¶' 
lines terminated by 'Þ' (
    clave_area,
    area_vta,
    @fecha_contable,
    sesion,
    @fecha_apertura,
    hora_apertura,av_p, 
    transaccion,
    operacion, 
    id_vta,
    tipo,
    origen,
    destino,
    @fecha_salida,
    hra_salida,
    f_boleto,
    asiento,
    pasajero,
    campo19,
    f_pago,
    ef,
    tb,pu,
    tr,
    doo,
    gp,
    cv,
    importe,
    formato_salto,
    @fecha_venta,
    hra_venta,
    corrida,
    empresa_corrida,
    t_boleto, 
    referencia,
    autorizacion,
    voucher,
    t_servicio,
    @fecha_cierre,
    razon_social,
    rfc,
    documento,
    empresa,
    fin,
    num_boletos) 

SET 

id = null,
fecha_contable = STR_TO_DATE(@fecha_contable, "%d/%m/%Y"),
fecha_apertura = STR_TO_DATE(@fecha_apertura, "%d/%m/%Y"),
fecha_salida = STR_TO_DATE(@fecha_salida, "%d/%m/%Y"),
fecha_venta = STR_TO_DATE(@fecha_venta, "%d/%m/%Y"),
fecha_cierre = STR_TO_DATE(@fecha_cierre, "%d/%m/%Y")

    --- script update ---
    UPDATE ventas306
    set num_boletos 
    where importe < 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En el update necesitas agregar un CASE.

```
update ventas306
    set num_boletos = case
    when importe < 0 then -1
    else 1
    end;
```

Para mayor detalles, revisa la referencia de MySQL en: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/case.html